# Backbone view undefined is not a function conflict

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have these 2 views:

Show View

```
define(['backbone', 'hbs!tmpl/show_tmpl', 'item/hide'],
    function (Backbone, Hide) {
        return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                console.log('initialize a UserLogin ItemView');

                console.log(Hide); // this comes in as undefined
            }, ...
```

Hide View

```
define(['backbone', 'hbs!tmpl/hide_tmpl', 'item/hide', 'item/show'],
    function (Backbone, Hide, Show) {
        return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                console.log('initialize a UserLogin ItemView');

                console.log(Hide);
                console.log(Show);
            }, ...
```

The issue is that `console.log(Hide);` in the `Show View` comes in as `undefined`

If I remove `'item/hide'` from the `Hide View`, then it works fine.

The idea is that I need to be able to do :

```
var hide = new Hide();
hide.methodOnShow();
```

in `Show View` and

```
var show = new Show();
show.methodOnHide();
```

in the `Hide View`

addon: if this helps, the 2 views are each opening a modal, so from the show modal i click a lick and open the hide modal and vice versa.

If i refresh the pages before opening each modal they work fine, but not opening them from inside a open modal.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: is `item/hide` a hide View  and `item/show` a show View?

Comment: not necessarily, they just get instantiate so i can call the `methodOnHide` methods

Comment: wait, require js resolves deps by file name, so if you need to load HideView via item/hide - you will get circullar deps as hide view need itself to load module. Close case with showView. it needs hide view, but HideView need ShowView to start.

Comment: As i can see you need to organize some logic with some toggle between these types of views, the good practice is to use Controller for such interactions. Controller loads both views and manage it in runtime. Is you could provide some information what you are going to reach i could help you to refactor you code

Comment: In the array of dependencies, can you put hbs!tmpl/show_tmpl dependency at last and try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
initialize: function () {
    require(['application', 'item/hide'], function (App, Hide) {
        ...
    });
}, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

the dependencies without return should be added at end( after the other parameters )

```
define(['backbone',  'item/hide','hbs!tmpl/show_tmpl'],
    function (Backbone, Hide) {
        return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                console.log('initialize a UserLogin ItemView');

                console.log(Hide); // this comes in as undefined
            }, ...
```